# kReachabilityChangedNotification crash in Reachability.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

I'm seeing a lot of crash reports from HockeyApp in Reachability.m, line 487 but I can't replicate it myself.

Here's the code surrounding that line:

```
    // this makes sure the change notification happens on the MAIN THREAD
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                                                        object:self];
    });
```

With the crash happening on the postNotificationName:object: method.

For context, I am using [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit), which in turn uses Reachability and is causing this crash.

**EDIT**:

The crash is a SIGSEGV exception. [here's](https://gist.github.com/KiranPanesar/6d6f9d525c498428f538) a sample crash report that was submitted.

I'm seeing this crash on all iOS versions we support (5.0-7.0).

Comment: What kind of crash do you get? OS version?

Comment: Symbolicate the crash report, and fire up the zombies debugger.  You've got a premature deallocation to find.

Comment: @CodaFi HockeyApp said this is the symbolicated report?

Comment: @KiranPanesar: look for the listeners of this notification , check if they did unregister properly in the dealloc

Comment: Then just fire up instruments.